# Authenticated on ADFS with Python

Tags: python, authentication, single-sign-on, adfs

We are using Microsoft ADFS at my company for single sign-on to access all the different internal tools.

I would like to know how I can reproduce my manual sign-in (in Google chrome for example) to be authenticated in Python.
I basically wrote a Python script downloading a file from one of our internal tools but to make it work, I have to make it open the link by Google Chrome where I'm already authenticated (I entered my login/password on the webpage before).
I want to avoid that step and have it directly downloaded by the script but for that I need to be authenticated in Python.

Do you know how I could do that please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @Pierre, have you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a way to do that

Comment: Just to revisit this, any change? Pierre & @Magnus Gustasvsson

Comment: In the end I had not been able to do it in a more elegant way and gave up, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Selenium with Python to control Chrome. Something like this:

```
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

from settings import url, username, password

xvfb = Xvfb()
xvfb.start()

browser = Chrome()
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element_by_id("usernameinput").send_keys(username)
browser.find_element_by_id("passwordinput").send_keys(password)
browser.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
```

If anyone knows of a more elegant way, I'm interested to hear about it as well.